# macOS (BSD) vs GNU grep multiple pattern inconsistency

Tags: grep, gnu, bsd, bugs

I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.6

```
$ grep --version
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD

$ ggrep --version
ggrep (GNU grep) 3.1
Packaged by Homebrew
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

---

I am doing a set intersection:

**BSD**

```
$ grep -Fx --color -e '1' -e '21' <(echo 1; echo 21;)
1 # Where is the 21? Intersection of the same set should return the same set.

# -F for fixed strings
# -x to match the whole line
# --color just to make sure what was matched
# two patterns '1' then '21'. Should be a logical OR of the two patterns
# so a line matches if it matches either '1' or '21'
```

The input is the same as the two patterns. `{1, 21}`

If I flip the patterns on BSD, it works:

```
$ grep -Fx --color -e '21' -e '1' <(echo 1; echo 21;)
1
21
```

---

**GNU**

```
$ ggrep -Fx --color -e '1' -e '21' <(echo 1; echo 21;)
1  # works as expected
21
```

---

Is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. OpenBSD `grep` (without `--color`) works as expected.

Comment: What happens if you use `\|` ? As in `grep -Fx --color '21\|1' < (echo 1; echo 21;)` it does also look like a bug to me ...

Comment: Good catch, @JdeBP